# Are the following initializations equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, auto, list-initialization

I read that often **list-initialization** is preferred over the 'old' way of using round braces, because they don't allow **narrowing conversions**.
The `auto` keyword has similar attributes, in that it avoids conversions at all.
I wonder whether the following two statements are equivalent:

```cpp
auto a = SomeClass(arg_a, arg_b);
auto b = SomeClass{arg_a, arg_b};
```

That is, apart from the fact that b has a different name than a ;)

By equivalent, i mean that for whatever arguments `SomeClass` takes, in whatever situation, i can replace the expression leading to the construction of **a**, with the construction leading to the construction of **b**, provided of course that i am using the `auto` keyword.
Is this the case, or are there any pitfalls/considerations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They may or may not be the same, it depends on the type.  For instance, if you have a `std::vector` then

```
auto vec1 = std::vector<int>(1, 2);
```

calls the constructor with the form of

```
vector( size_type count,
        const T& value,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Which creates a vector of size `1` with the element having the value of `2`.  With

```
auto vec1 = std::vector<int>{1, 2};
```

the

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

constructor is called which creates a vector of size `2` containing the elements `{1, 2}`.

Comment: Very interesting, haven't thought about that!
Is it equivalent for classes that don't  have a constructor taking an initializer_list as argument?

Comment: @ancientchild Yes.  If there is no `std::initializer_list` constructor then they will be the same.  It's once there is a `std::initializer_list` constructor that you have to be careful, or design the constructors in such a way where this can't happen.